# extension.js not updating accordingly to changes in extension.ts in vscode extension api

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I'm new to developing within the vscode extension api. I'm working with other people on an extension together so I've cloned their repo but I notice that any changes I make to extension.ts, they are not replicated within extension.js in the "out" folder, which I'm guessing is what vscode runs when I press f5. I've made my own separate extension with the same code and extension.js updates fine. I was wondering if there was any way to fix extension.js not updating? Thanks.

Comment: run the Typescript compiler manually or use the watch npm script

Comment: I see appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
yarn watch
```

For it to start listening to changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because I`ve opened my extension source code workspace not from the folder. The extension was created but from the parent folder.

So I had folders like that:

- vscode_extension_test:

  - my_extension:

    - (extension files)

And the extension root folder was my_extension, but I`ve opened it from vscode_extension_test folder.